# What is the best way to add a gradient as the top layer of a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, gradient

I have a custom UIView class which I add a UIScrollView on top of. What i am trying to do is add a gradient to the UIView's layer so that is visible above the scroll view. Currently i am doing it this way:

```
[self.layer insertSublayer:self.leftShadowLayer atIndex:[self.layer.sublayers count]];
[self.layer insertSublayer:self.rightShadowLayer atIndex:[self.layer.sublayers count]];
```

but this seems a little hackish and prone to issues for some reason. Is there any other preferred way of adding a sublayer is the top layer in a view regardless of what else is added to the view's layers?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Draw the gradient using CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents() or CGGradientCreateWithColors().
The documentation lies at-

[CGGradientRef guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: uhh, my question is about how to draw the gradient its how to make set it as the top layer?

Answer (score 0):

See the sample code to draw a CALayer, which u can add to a UIView's layer property.

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext

{
```

//   self.opacity=.5;
    CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

```
//CGPathMoveToPoint(thePath,NULL,100.0f,200.f);

CGPoint aOnePoint=CGPointMake(cgpoint.x,tipPoint.y);
CGPoint aTwoPoint=CGPointMake(cgpoint.x+5,460);
CGPoint aThreePoint=CGPointMake(320,100);
CGPoint aFourPoint=CGPointMake(320,tipPoint.y-25);
CGPoint points[]={aOnePoint,aTwoPoint,aFourPoint};
CGPathAddLines(thePath, NULL,points,3);



CGContextBeginPath(theContext);
CGContextAddPath(theContext, thePath);
//CAGradientLayer here...using the CGCreateGradient methods.


CGContextSetLineWidth(theContext,2.0f);

CGSize theShadowSize = CGSizeMake(4.0f,4.0f);

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(theContext, theShadowSize,3,[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(theContext,[UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(theContext);

CFRelease(thePath);
```

}

this way you can draw your own layer and add it to .layer property of a view.
Notice that we have to override the `- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)theContext` to have a custom layer. May need to call

Hope that helps..

Comment: insert the layer at index 0 in order to make it the topmost layer.

Comment: index 0 is bottom layer not top

Comment: is addSublayer:(CALayer *)layer method not working in your case?